# How to URL rewrite with my case

Tags: php, apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I know that this site has many questions about URL rewriting. But as a newbie, I could not find the correct answer for my case.

My question is: I would like to rewrite the original URL like this: when user visit:

```
http://username.example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h...
```

the apache will process request as

```
http://example.com/index.php?user=username&a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h...
```

According to what I knew, the solution could be using QUERY STRING, but I don't know how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks,

Comment: What are you asking? How to make apache to support PATH_INFO? Or, how to write a php function to get a string with PATH_INFO?

Comment: I mean when visitor access the address: http://username.example.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h, they actually visit address: http://example.com/index.php?user=username&a=b&c=d&e=f&g=h

Comment: I am not sure what server software you are using. According to your needs, I think you can google "**php subdomain**" or "**apache subdomain**" for some helps. 
After you have configured the sub domain, you'd better use a php framework like **Laravel** because it's easier to meet your needs. 
 [How to configure routes in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need for this is to create Dynamic sub-domain. [create dynamic subdomain](https://www.9lessons.info/2016/03/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomains-using-php-and-htaccess.html) link will help you in this. Use following config for your case:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?user=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?user=%1
```

once this is in place, you can add more conditions for the remaining parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It not work for me. But I have just found the solution, which is copied from Wordpress .htaccess file, then I use php to explode the REQUEST_URI form $_SERVER. Thanks again :)